# mysterious behaviour of python built-in method filter in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the below fact:

```py
a = list(range(10))

res = list(a)
for i in a:
  if i in {3, 5}:
    print('>>>', i)
    res = filter(lambda x: x != i, res)

print(list(res))

>>> 3
>>> 5
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

So neither `3` nor `5` was removed, but `9` is gone...

If i force convert the filter object to list, then it work as expected:

```py
a = list(range(10))

res = list(a)
for i in a:
  if i in {3, 5}:
    print('>>>', i)
    # Here i force to convert filter object to list then it will work as expected.
    res = list(filter(lambda x: x != i, res))

print(list(res))

>>> 3
>>> 5
[0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I can feel this is due to that the filter object is a generator, but cannot exactly interpreter how the generator cause this **consistent** weird behaviour, please help to elaborate the underlying rationalities.

Comment: Late binding of `i` in the lambda. At execution time rather than when the lambda is defined.  Try it with `lambda x, j=i: x != j` for early binding.

Comment: If you convert to list, then you force immediate execution while inside the `for` loop. Without it, the execution of the generator is delayed until you iterate over it, by which time `i` has value 9. Couple this with the late binding of `i`, and this accounts for the observed behaviour.

Comment: @alaniwi ah yeah, got it, how can i miss this, was always in mind for the js event bubbling, then the question looks quite misleading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour arises from a combination of two facts:

1. The lambda function contains the variable `i` taken from the surrounding scope, which is only evaluated at execution time.  Consider this example:

```
>>> func = lambda x: x != i  # i does not even need to exist yet
>>> i = 3
>>> func(3)  # now i will be used
False
```

2. Because `filter` returns a generator, the function is evaluated lazily, when you actually iterate over it, rather than when `filter` is called.

The combined effect of these, in the first example, is that by the time that you iterate over the  `filter` object, `i` has the value of 9, and this value is used in the lambda function.

The desired behaviour can be obtained by removing either (or both) of the two combined factors mentioned above:

1. In the lambda, force early binding by creating a closure, where you use the value of `i` as the default value of a parameter (say `j`), so in place of `lambda x: x != i`, you would use:

```
lambda x, j=i: x != j
```

- The expression for the default value (i.e. `i`) is evaluated when the lambda is defined, and by calling the lambda with only one argument (`x`) this ensures that you do not override this default at execution time.

or:

2. Force early execution of all iterations of the generator by converting to list immediately (as you have observed).